# Custom icon for each NSUserNotification?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications, nsusernotification

Is there any way to provide **custom** icons for each `NSUserNotification`, instead of the default app logo? Like the `iconData` parameter in `Growl`.

I want to show "Someone has just posted something" with the photo of this "someone".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently not (Mountain Lion). You should post a [feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Answer (score 8):

You still cannot change the (default) image showing your app's icon, but starting in OS X Mavericks you can in addition display an additional image using the new property `contentImage`, e.g. like this:

[image: custom image in NSUserNotification]

This new property isn't documented in the `NSUserNotification` class reference, but mentioned in the [Foundation Release Notes for OS X 10.9](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000742).

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been dead for 5 years, but in case someone finds that question and is still looking for a solution, there is that one:

https://github.com/indragiek/NSUserNotificationPrivate

I've tested it in macOS Sierra and it still works. Just be warned, quoting the project creator:

> **This should go without saying, but using any of this will result in**
>   **your app being rejected from the MAS** (Mac Apple Store) **and potentially breaking if the**
>   **APIs change**.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a related answer about NSUserNotifications I found your question. Officially it's not yet supported. But I wrote a little custom control you can use that may fit your needs. Take a look [on this Github repository](https://github.com/phranck/CNUserNotification).